# Mesh exporting inconsistent with blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature, export

I have a mesh in blender that I have been working with and am having an issue with exporting (regardless of the file type).

My mesh looks like this and have a number of poses in each animation frame:
[image]

Upon export and re-import I am getting this:
[image]

I am not sure where to begin troubleshooting/what would cause a disconnect between what is being displayed and what is being exported. If I just try to link or append it comes through without issue. If I go to a much older version to export there is no issue. Please let me know if any other info would be useful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Something additional I found that may help:  
In blender: if i delete my shape keys so that I delete the "Basis" key last it will cause the mesh to go into that distorted shape.

Comment: It seems to be fixed by deleting all shape keys. I didnt want to lose my facial expressions so I highlighted all vertices from the neck down > selected mesh > vertices > shape propagate
Cant say I really understand why this all happened but it looks to be working as expected.